# как объединить в Postgresql json ключи с непустым значением?

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице:

```
id  |      filters        |             params
--------------------------------------------------------
1      {"a":"","b":"b"}      {"a":"a", "b": "", "c":""}
2           ....                        .....
```

Как объединить в поле filters (update) c полем params так чтобы не было повторных ключей и значение для ключа бралось с не пустого значения, если такое имеется. В результате:

```
id  |      filters                 |         params
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1      {"a":"а","b":"b", "c":""}      {"a":"a", "b": "", "c":""}
2             ....                           .....
```

Comment: А если у вас в фильтрах `"a":"a111"`, а в параметрах `"a":"z999"`, то что должно быть в итоге?

Comment: остаться значение которое в фильтрах